# Como fazer SELECT para pegar dados em tabelas diferentes e com id's diferentes

Tags: php, mysql

Tem 3 tabelas

- Na tabela `entrada` tem os dados: `id_entrada`, `id_empresa`, `id_categoria` e id_subcategoria.
- Na tabela `cat_entradas` tenho: `id_categoria` e `categoria`.
- E na tabela `sub_cate_entrada` tenho: `id_subcategoria` e `subcategoria`.

Já peguei os dois ids (id_categoria e id_subcategoria) na tabela entrada.

Agora, preciso pegar a categoria e a subcategoria, nas suas respectivas tabelas. Tem como eu fazer isso em um comando SQL só, ou terei que fazer 2, um para cada tabela?

```
    <?php
    $pdo = conectar();
    $this->dataConta=$pdo->prepare("SELECT categoria, subcategoria FROM entrada WHERE id_entrada=:id_entrada AND id_empresa=:id_empresa"); 
    $this->dataConta->bindValue(":id_entrada", 30); 
    $this->dataConta->bindValue(":id_empresa", 1); 
    $this->dataConta->execute(); 
    $res = $this->dataConta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $res['categoria']." - ". $res['subcategoria'];
    $pdo = null;
```

Comment: Tem como, mas está difícil de entender exatamente o que quer. Se tiver um exemplo de dados, umas duas linhas para cada tabela, mais umas duas linhas para os resultados que já tem e que deseja, ajuda bastante a responder. As queries que já construiu também ajudam.

Comment: @fbiazi, veja se o código que coloquei, ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar dois inner joins, uma só query retorna todos os resultados que você precisa:

```
$resultado = $pdo->query(
    "SELECT e.id_categoria, e.id_subcategoria, c.categoria, s.subcategoria
    FROM entrada e
    INNER JOIN cat_entradas c ON c.id_categoria  = e.id_categoria
    INNER JOIN sub_cate_entrada s ON s.id_subcategoria = e.id_subcategoria"
);
while ($r = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $r['id_categoria'] . ': ' . $r['categoria'] . '; ' . $r['id_subcategoria '] . ': ' . $r['subcategoria'] . '#';
}
```

Assim lê campos de várias tabelas ao mesmo tempo. As letras "e", "c" e "s" são alias para as tabelas.

O exemplo imprime valores para cada linha lida.

Comment: Certo @fbiazi, vou tentar isso.

Comment: acho que faltou uma "," nessa linha: 
"SELECT e.id_categoria, e.id_subcategoria c.categoria, s.subcategoria FROM entrada e", não?

Comment: Faltou sim. Corrigido.